# PHP: how do we make a joint, numeric-associative array; how do I look up the index by itself?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, indexing, descriptor

Here's the generic workaround I am using:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/2tiPvN

```
$j=0;
$paper = array('copier' => "Copier and Multipurpose",
               'inkjet' => "Injet Printer",
               'laser' => "Laser Printer",
               'photo' => "Photo Paper");

foreach ($paper as $index => $description)
{
  echo "$j, $index: $description
";
  $j++;
}
```

I want to have numeric identifiers and keyword identifiers.

Meanwhile, because foreach ($paper as $description) gives the description and

```
foreach ($paper as $index => $description)
```

gives the index and then the description..., is there a way to just get the index in a foreach, without having to specify a variable for the description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure what you mean, but maybe

```
foreach(array_keys($ary) as $key)...
```

Comment: It looks like the index is becoming a numeric value, and the description is becoming the index.  So, how do I get the description?

Comment: Same story: `array_values` returns only the values(`description`) in a numerically-indexed array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `array_keys()`:

```
$indexes = array_keys($paper);
```

See: http://php.net/function.array-keys

Comment: Is it possible to get the array key, the index, and the description all in a single foreach loop? http://codepad.viper-7.com/rNYeil

Comment: array key and index are the same thing. i dont get your question.

Comment: I think it is not possible because in another answer, someone said: "You can't have key->value->value.  You can only have key-value pairs."  I'm looking for something whose printr() would return something like this: Array([0]->'dog'->"Canine" [1]->'cat'->"Feline"...)".

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($paper as $key => $description) { ... }
```

is the syntax to get both key and value in the loop.

As for keying the array with both numeric and textual values, PHP's arrays don't really support that. But nothing says you can't duplicate the values internally:

```
$array = (
   0 => 'Copier and ...',
   'copier' => 'Copier and ...'
   ...
);
```

Note that with this version, foreach will return both versions. You'd have to do a regular `for ($i = 0; .....) { }` loop to catch only the numeric keys.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(array_keys($ary) as $key)... its give index

array['0']=>'copier'
array['1']=> 'inkjet'
          array['2']=>     'laser' 
               array['3']=>'photo' 
similarly for values
foreach(array_values($ary) as $value)...
```